# Window without border in Windows 7

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, windows-7, border

I try to remove the border of a WPF Window. In Window XP worked fine. In Windows 7 the title bar disappear (this is ok), but the window border didn't disappear: this is the problem.

**The question: what I must to change to remove the border?**

This is the XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="261" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,29,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Some text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" FontSize="36" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I attached a print screen bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode)  to `NoResize`:

```
<Window ... WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `AllowsTransparency="True"` and the border will disappear